# Cant Find REGEX match for Multiline String

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I am trying to make regular expression to search a string for a multi-line pattern. An example of the string is:

```
!
map-class frame-relay TempMap_1
 frame-relay cir 1536000
 frame-relay bc 15360
 frame-relay mincir 281000
 frame-relay adaptive-shaping becn
 service-policy output AB_TEMP_F1536K_0-256K-384K-128K_18
logging trap debugging
logging source-interface Loopback1
logging 136.91.111.21
```

The matching string i am trying to extract is

```
map-class frame-relay TempMap_1
 frame-relay cir 1536000
 frame-relay bc 15360
 frame-relay mincir 281000
 frame-relay adaptive-shaping becn
 service-policy output AB_TEMP_F1536K_0-256K-384K-128K_18
```

The pattern i have

```
map-class frame-relay TempMap_1[]*

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("map-class frame-relay TempMap_1[]*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

I am not quite sure to put within [] to make the regular expression work. I am using Java and Pattern.DOTALL to match string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your regular expressions doesn't account for line-breaks and other white space. Replace the blanks in your regexp with \s for example

Comment: I would suggest reading a primer on regex functions so you understand what they are and how they work. regular-expressions.info is a decent resource. Regarding your issue, can you describe in detail what you're looking for? A line that starts with `map-class` followed by an arbitrary number of lines indented by a single space?

Comment: @CAustin : I have gone through a lot of online tutorials. I know a lot about regex, but still not grasped multi-line stuff quite well. Single lines are not an issue. I am trying to find out "map-class frame-relay TempMap_1" followed by all lines after it starting with a blank space till the first line that doesn't start with blank space. Like in the above example "logging trap debugging", should be ending criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java *8*, you may leverage the indentation here and use

```
String regex = "map-class frame-relay TempMap_1.*(?:\\R\\h+.*)*";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/on9qjR/1). *Do **NOT** use `Pattern.DOTALL` with this pattern.*

**Details**

- `map-class frame-relay TempMap_1` - a literal substring
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\\R\\h+.*)*` - 0+ consecutive sequences of:

  - `\\R` - a line break sequence (in Java 7, use `(?:\r\n?|\n)`, it should suffice)
  - `\\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces (in Java 7, use `[^\\S\r\n]+`)
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/jA1x7n):

```
String s = "!\nmap-class frame-relay TempMap_1\n frame-relay cir 1536000\n frame-relay bc 15360\n frame-relay mincir 281000\n frame-relay adaptive-shaping becn\n service-policy output AB_TEMP_F1536K_0-256K-384K-128K_18\nlogging trap debugging\nlogging source-interface Loopback1\nlogging 136.91.111.21";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("map-class frame-relay TempMap_1.*(?:\\R\\h+.*)*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
[map-class frame-relay TempMap_1
 frame-relay cir 1536000
 frame-relay bc 15360
 frame-relay mincir 281000
 frame-relay adaptive-shaping becn
 service-policy output AB_TEMP_F1536K_0-256K-384K-128K_18]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Awesome! That was really nice!